# Wordpress doesn't use custom page template after update

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, child-theming

I use the Gridlove theme. I created a page and a custom template for that page inside a gridlove-child theme. Everything worked as it should until the wordpress update (Wordpress Version 6.2.2, Gridlove version 1.9.5).

Now the custom page is still an option, which I can choose for that page inside the page edit view, but it doesn't have any affect. The page has taken a default view, which cannot be modified even if I choose any other custom template. The files in child theme are unmodified.

I also created a custom theme for custom posts, which are displayed on this page, which remains unaffected and still works (uses the correct custom template) after the update.

Has anyone ever come across this problem before?

Comment: Update: I created another custom template, which is empty. I put this one into gridlove folder (not child). This one can also be selected when editing the page, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem with wordpress 6.4.1.

I had to downgrade to 6.3 (replacing wp-admin and wp-includes folders)